# Populate data from database in <p:selectOneMenu> using jsf2

Tags: mysql, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

> I'm using selectOneMenu from primefaces to populate data from mysql database, but i constantly get empty fields and i dont receive any errors.
>   Can somebody explain what am i doing wrong?
>
> This is my code:

xhtml file:

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="point" value="#{pointController.selectedPoint}"
                     var="items_var"> 

         <f:selectItems value="#{pointController.points}" var="points_var" 
                        itemLabel="#{points_var.name}" itemValue="#{points_var.name}"/>

    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Managed bean:

```
    @ManagedBean(name = "pointController")
    @SessionScoped

    public class PointController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
        private ethoam.entity.PointFacade ejbFacade;
        private List<point> points;
        private point selectedPoint;
        private point[] selectedPoints;
        private List<Point> selectedPointsList;
        private SelectItem[] PointNamesOptions;

        public PointController() {
                  this.initList();
        }

        @PostConstruct
        private void initList() {

        points = new ArrayList<point>(pointControllerConverter.getPoints().values());


    }

        // getters setters
     }
```

And Converter class:

```
    public static class PointControllerConverter implements Converter {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PointPU")
    private static EntityManager ejbfacade;

    public static Map<String, point> points = new HashMap<String, point>();

    public Map<String,point> getPoints() {

    points = (Map<String, point>) ejbfacade.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("SELECT d FROM point d WHERE d.name = :name");
    return points;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        PointController controller = (PointController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "pointController");
        return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
    }

    java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
        java.lang.Integer key;
        key = Integer.valueOf(value);
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(value);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof point) {
            point o = (point) object;
            return getStringKey(o.getIdPoint());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + Point.class.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a String as the value (`itemValue="#{points_var.name}"`) and your component is expecting an instance of **point**.

This is one of the changes you will need to consider:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="point" value="#{pointController.selectedPoint}" var="items_var"> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{pointController.points}" var="points_var" itemLabel="#{points_var.name}" itemValue="#{points_var}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I've also noticed that your are not populating the `private List<Point> points;` using the **PointFacade**. Instead, you are instantiating an ArrayList with values from an empty static Map inside PointControllerConverter.

Your question suggests that you are trying to populate a selectOnMenu with values from database (MySQL). In this case, you will need to rethink your strategy and start using some EJB (like the PointFacade) to fetch data from your Database.

Comment: How did you registered PointControllerConverter?

Comment: @FacesConverter(forClass = Point.class)

Comment: I've included some other considerations to my answer. I hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've done some changes and ran on another issue : Cant instantiate class. I edited the code, so you might take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check Once without using attributes - var, itemValue, itemLabel and you can also try writing the query in the getter itself .